# this.setState() is changing state to wrong value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to calculate some values and store them in the state for a later call to my api. I wrote the code and it is putting the wrong values in.

I have tried doing one setState() with everything being calculated and "set" in the function. I have tried making variables for all three functions I was calling previously. I have split the setState() into four different calls. I have double checked the functions are returning the correct values.

State:

```js
    state={
        stage: 0,
        ['Total Weight']: null,
        ['Calculated Yield']: null,
        ['Loan Grade']: null
    }
```

Function with problem:

```js
handleUnderwritingNext = () =>{

    //....Irrelevant code above

        else if(this.state.stage === 2){
            let amount = Number(this.state['Approved Amount'].replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
            let weight = oldSocres.ScoreCardCalc(this.state)
            let grade = Grade.getGrade(weight)
            if(amount>150000 && amount <=250000){
                var yeild = Yeild.large(weight)
                console.log("Next Grade: " + grade +", Weight: "+weight + ", Yeild: "+yeild) // Next Grade: 3, Weight: 51.12, Yeild: 7.15

                this.setState({...this.state, ['Loan Grade']:grade}, ()=>{console.log("State Grade: "+this.state['Loan Grade'])}) // State Grade: 0
                this.setState({...this.state, ['Calculated Yield']:yeild})
                this.setState({...this.state, ['Total Weight']:weight})
                this.setState({...this.state, stage: this.state.stage+1})                
            }

            else if(amount>50000 && amount <=150000){
                let yeild = Yeild.mid(weight)
                console.log("Next Grade: " + grade +", Weight: "+weight + ", Yeild: "+yeild) // Next Grade: 3, Weight: 51.12, Yeild: 7.15
                this.setState({...this.state, ['Loan Grade']:grade},()=>{console.log("State Grade: "+this.state['Loan Grade'])})// State Grade: 0
                this.setState({...this.state, ['Calculated Yield']:yeild})
                this.setState({...this.state, ['Total Weight']:weight})
                this.setState({...this.state, stage: this.state.stage+1})                
            }
           else{
               let yeild = Yeild.small(weight)
               console.log("Next Grade: " + grade +", Weight: "+weight + ", Yeild: "+yeild)// Next Grade: 3, Weight: 51.12, Yeild: 7.15
               this.setState({...this.state, ['Loan Grade']:grade},()=>{console.log("State Grade: "+this.state['Loan Grade'])})// State Grade: 0
               this.setState({...this.state, ['Calculated Yield']:yeild})
               this.setState({...this.state, ['Total Weight']:weight})
                this.setState({...this.state, stage: this.state.stage+1})                
            }

        }

        else if(this.state.stage === 3){

            this.setState({...this.state, stage: this.state.stage+1})            

        }
    }
```

The expected result should be the state values for :
`'Loan Grade' = 3, 'Total Weight' = 51.12, and 'Calculated Yeild' = 7.15`.  Currently it is setting the state to : `'Loan Grade' = "0", 'Total Weight' = 51.12, 'Calculated Yeild' = 0`

Comment: It seems like a really bad practice to update the state that way. Why not just build **one** object and then call `.setState()` just **once**?

Comment: Why do you  add `...this.state` ?

Comment: Exactly what @Pointy said. You also only need to call `this.setState` once per scope in your case.

Comment: If it were me I'd not only combine these into one setState call but I'd also use `setState(prev => ({ /* new state */ }))`

Comment: I started with the combined one and it wasn't working. I ran out of options so I tried breaking it up. The post was just the current version I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like my comment says, I'd combine the setState calls and use prev.

```
this.setState(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  ['Loan Grade']: grade,
  ['Calculated Yield']: yeild,
  ['Total Weight']:weight,
  stage: prev.stage + 1
}))
```

If it were me I'd also get rid of spaces in my object property names and just have grade, yield, and weight but that's just my preference.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I am VERY new to this and still trying to figure things out.

Comment: @AjDed no problem. I always say, try to keep things as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> Think of `setState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

`this.setState` does not update state right away, so when you make multiple calls in a row, `this.state` contains the old state. Try using the functional form of `this.setState`, to "append" to the latest version of the state.

```
this.setState(state => {...state, ['Loan Grade']:grade},()=>{console.log("State Grade: "+this.state['Loan Grade'])})// State Grade: 0
this.setState(state => {...state, ['Calculated Yield']:yeild})
this.setState(state => {...state, ['Total Weight']:weight})
this.setState(state => {...state, stage: this.state.stage+1})
```

Or, simply combine them all into one call to update state:

```
this.setState({
    ...state,
    ['Loan Grade']: grade,
    ['Calculated Yield']: yeild,
    stage: this.state.stage+1
});
```

Comment: I started with the combined one and it wasn't working. I ran out of options so I tried breaking it up. The post was just the current version I had.